# Numerals: двух сто or двести

Tags: числительные

Are these used interchangeably?
Both are given as two hundred by translators, so which one is used?

Comment: What translator told you 200 is двух сто?  Do you mean automated computer translators (which as a rule can suck pretty badly)?

Comment: I think Lawrence was trying to say: Двухста и Двести.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first one is simply incorrect, whatever you want to say. However, *двухсот* would be a genitive of *двести*:

> *Мне не хватает двухсот рублей.*

Answer (score 5):

- Именительный падеж — Двести
- Родительный падеж — Двухсот
- Дательный падеж — Двумстам
- Винительный падеж — Двести
- Творительный падеж — Двумястами
- Предложный падеж — О двухстах

### Примеры

- Не имей `двести` рублей, а имей `двести` друзей.
- Автомобиль развивает скорость до `двухсот` километров в час.
- `Двумстам` работникам цеха вручили премию.
- Проект был выполнен `двумястами` студентами МГУ.
- В `двухстах` метрах от дома лежал изуродованный труп.